# Rails params explain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-dropbox-like-file-sharing-site-with-ruby-on-rails--net-17940). 
I am not able to understand `params[]` in rails .PLease don't provide me links to rails guides. I have already read that still it is not clear. My doubts are

1. What arguments I can give
2. What is basically params[:folder] & params[:id]
3. If it is the column name which we are passing then I dont have folder column in my table. Columns are in my folders table: id, name, created_at, updated_at
4. I am using rails 4.2.4 so some places I have read attr_accessible was used but now it is obsolete. So what to use instead of   attr_accessible?

   ```
   class FoldersController < ApplicationController 
     before_filter :authenticate_user! 

     def index 
       @folders = current_user.folders 
     end

     def show 
       @folder = current_user.folders.find(params[:id]) 
     end

     def new
       @folder = current_user.folders.new
     end

     def create 
       @folder = current_user.folders.new(params[:folder]) 
     end
   end
   ```

This is my 2nd controller. My doubt is what is folder_id over here

```
    class HomeController < ApplicationController 

      def browse 
        #get the folders owned/created by the current_user 
        @current_folder = current_user.folders.find_by_id(params[:folder_id])   
      end
    end
```

Comment: `params` contains request parameters. If you navigate to `/folders/1234?foo=bar`, then `params[:id]` will be `1234` and `params[:foo]` will equal `"bar"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `params` are a series of `key-value` pairs comes from a browser with a page request. For an `HTTP GET` request, the `params` are encoded in the `URL`.

For a request like this:

```
http://www.example.com/?foo=1&bar=cat
```

then `params[:foo]` would be `"1"` and `params[:bar]` would be `"cat"`.

In `HTTP/HTML`, the `params` are really just a series of `key-value` pairs where the `key` and the `value` are strings, but `Rails` has a special syntax for making the `params` be a `Hash` with hashes inside.

For a request like this:

```
http://www.example.com/folders/55/?folder[name]=bubble&folder[size]=1324
```

then,
`params[:folder]` would be a `Hash`,
`params[:folder][:name]` would be `"bubble"` and
`params[:folder][:size]` would be `"1324"`. Also,
`params[:id]` would be `"55"`.

---

`Rails 4` now uses `strong parameters`.

Protecting attributes are now done in the controller. Like this example:

```
class ArticleController < ApplicationController
  def create
    Article.create(article_params)
  end

private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:name, :category)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `params` object is simply a hash containing the parameters sent to the server with the request. For example, if you access the endpoint `/folders/1` with a `GET` request, meaning you're running the `FoldersController#show` action, you'll have a hash that includes an `:id` key (which is, in turn, declared in the routes, since you're probably using the `resources :folders` method). You can access it using `params[:id]`, thus returning `1`. If you pass any other parameters in the query string, they will be available as well: accessing `/folders/1?show_details=true` will result in a `params` object containing a `:show_details` key, mapped to the value `true`.